# Data Mining/Retrieval Question

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, data-mining, data-retrieval

Our SQL Server 2005 database has nearly 100 different tables. We are going to provide a feature to search some information according to the user defined filters. Our filter configuration going to be quite complicated. A user can easily create a filter that joins over 20 tables with complicated conditions.

In order to reduce the complexity of the joining, we are planning to create couple of SQL Server views. But that solution itself doesn't seems to be enough to simplify the SQL. We are going to generate the SQL according to the filter configuration. The SQL will be generated dynamically. (I am not sure how long that SQL would be… Is there any maximum length for SqlCommand?) SP is another option...

Have you come across a similar situation? Do you have any good advise/solution for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to be aware of some of the pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a reporting database that de-normalizes your data, so you don't need the complicated queries.  Also make sure that any queries are parameterized to avoid sql injection attacks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you think about creating a set of views rather than a reporting database?

Comment: @CharithJ: views will simplify a schema for end-users, but they do not have any performance benefits over the raw SQL unless they are materialised views.

Comment: @Mitch: What if they are Indexed views?

Comment: @CharithJ: yes Indexed views will almost certainly provide performance benefits, but they can add an extra layer of complexity and have some gotchas...

Comment: @Mitch : Finally I came up with Table value functions which work fine in this case.